# document.onclick or window.onclick prevents input type color from opening

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, onclick

I am making a global selection functionality and I tried using the following methods:

```
document.onclick = callback;
```

or

```
window.onclick = callback;
```

**Problem is that these methods prevent input type="color" from functioning (opening), it seems to override something and I can't find out what exactly.**

```
<input type="color">
```

So when I click the input type color it also triggers my *onclick* event thus preventing the input color from opening, are there ways around this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. All I had to do is check the click target element's type and simple "return" from the callback if the type is "color".

`if (event.target.type && event.target.type === 'color') return;`